# Azure Logic App - Office365 connection creation by ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create ARM template for my logic app for CI/CD release pipeline. I have a task to send email at the end of the flow.

1. I wanted to create Office365 connection dynamically and add to the step in ARM template. Can you please help on how is this done?
2. Also, is it necessary to use multi-factor enabled office365 account for it? Can we use service account to send email?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to resolve your issue? If yes, then please let us know, how did you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Currently afaik it’s easily done to authenticate the office365 connector. I’ve tried so myself.

You can create the connector in ARM and [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2016/02/23/deploying-in-the-logic-apps-preview-refresh/) will show you how to make a connector of your choosing in an ARM template.

The problems is you can’t authenticate the endpoint using the client_credentials flow which means you can’t authenticate the user in a none interactive way.

There is an [example](https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth) in GitHub which will handle the authentication for you but requires a user to log in. I tried using this the other week to test using client_credentials (non-interactive) flow but I was unable to authenticate.

Comment: this article is pretty old, I don't know you were able to resolve your issue. Please let us know how did you resolve this issue?